# Изменение ImageView в диалоге

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь сделать программное изменение ресурса `ImageView` в xml файле диалога:

```
 public void dialogend(Activity activity){
        View view = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.gameover, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        adb.setView(view);

        AlertDialog alert = adb.create();

        ImageView imageView;
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.zvrez);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.vek11);

        alert.show();
}
```

Файл gameover.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/zvrez"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

На строке `imageView.setImageResource` происходит краш. Что делать?

Comment: Первым делом нужно прилагать лог при краше, ну и, видимо, искать имидж нужно не в вакууме, а в своей отинфлейтненой вьюхе `imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.zvrez);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хотя какая именно у вас ошибка вы не говорите, но это наверняка NPE, вызванная тем, что вы не там ищете свой **ImageView**. Его надо искать в той разметке, кою вы назначили диалогу. т.е., вместо

```
ImageView imageView;
imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.zvrez);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.vek11);
```

, где вы ищете в разметке активити, надо искать в View диалога, т.е замените ваш код на:

```
ImageView imageView;
imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.zvrez);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.vek11);
```